# StreamTokenizer mangles integers and loose periods

Tags: java, tokenize

I've appropriated and modified the below code which does a pretty good job of tokenizing Java code using Java's StreamTokenizer. Its number handling is problematic, though:

1. it turns all integers into doubles. I can get past that by testing num % 1 == 0, but this feels like a hack
2. More critically, a . following whitespace is treated as a number. "Class .method()" is legal Java syntax, but the resulting tokens are [Word "Class"], [Whitespace " "], [Number 0.0], [Word "method"], [Symbol "("], and [Symbol ")"]

I'd be happy turning off StreamTokenizer's number parsing entirely and parsing the numbers myself from word tokens, but commenting st.parseNumbers() seems to have no effect.

```
public class JavaTokenizer {

private String code;

private List<Token> tokens;

public JavaTokenizer(String c) {
    code = c;
    tokens = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void tokenize() {
    try {
        // Create the tokenizer
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(code);
        StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(sr);

        // Java-style tokenizing rules
        st.parseNumbers();
        st.wordChars('_', '_');
        st.eolIsSignificant(false);

        // Don't want whitespace tokens
        //st.ordinaryChars(0, ' ');

        // Strip out comments
        st.slashSlashComments(true);
        st.slashStarComments(true);

        // Parse the file
        int token;
        do {
            token = st.nextToken();
            switch (token) {
            case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
                // A number was found; the value is in nval
                double num = st.nval;
                if(num % 1 == 0)
                  tokens.add(new IntegerToken((int)num);
                else
                  tokens.add(new FPNumberToken(num));
                break;
            case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
                // A word was found; the value is in sval
                String word = st.sval;
                tokens.add(new WordToken(word));
                break;
            case '"':
                // A double-quoted string was found; sval contains the contents
                String dquoteVal = st.sval;
                tokens.add(new DoubleQuotedStringToken(dquoteVal));
                break;
            case '\'':
                // A single-quoted string was found; sval contains the contents
                String squoteVal = st.sval;
                tokens.add(new SingleQuotedStringToken(squoteVal));
                break;
            case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL:
                // End of line character found
                tokens.add(new EOLToken());
                break;
            case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF:
                // End of file has been reached
                tokens. add(new EOFToken());
                break;
            default:
                // A regular character was found; the value is the token itself
                char ch = (char) st.ttype;
                if(Character.isWhitespace(ch))
                    tokens.add(new WhitespaceToken(ch));
                else
                    tokens.add(new SymbolToken(ch));
                break;
            }
        } while (token != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF);
        sr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

public List<Token> getTokens() {
    return tokens;
}

}
```

Comment: I've played with the various built-in Java tokenizer classes, and my take-away is that they aren't really very functional.  Look at a real parser like [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/).  (They have a Java parser all pre-configured and ready to go, btw, don't try to make your own.)

Comment: Maybe you could add `.` to the "word chars", see javadoc

Comment: Oh, I know, but ANTLR is huge and complex and WAY more functionality than I need, whereas this is just one bug away from suiting my needs perfectly, so if I can get this resolved, it'll be hours less work than replacing the whole system

Comment: @RC, interesting. I'm not sure I understand the javadoc on StreamTokenizer.wordChars(). It seems to say that only characters from firstArg to secondArg are used to identify words, but the code sample I stole has both args set to underscore, and it still recognizes words. I also tried setting this to .wordChars(0x23,0xFF), which includes period, and could not discern any difference in behavior.

Comment: I'm no expert in StringTokenizer, sorry, if antlr is too big for you, maybe you should take a look at [parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/wiki/Java-Parser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parseNumbers() in "on" by default. Use resetSyntax() to turn off number parsing and all other predefined character types, then enable what you need.

That said, manual number parsing might get tricky with accounting for dots and exponents... With a scanner and regular expressions it should be relatively straightforward to implement your own tokenizer, tailored exactly to your needs. For an example, you may want to take a look at the `Tokenizer` inner class here: https://github.com/stefanhaustein/expressionparser/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/kobjects/expressionparser/ExpressionParser.java (about 120 LOC at the end)

Comment: That makes so much more sense. It's working much better now. I wish the documentation was a little more clear about parseNumbers() having no effect unless resetSyntax() had been called.

Answer (score 0):

I'll look into parboiled when I have a chance. In the meantime, the disgusting workaround I implemented to get it working is:

```
private static final String DANGLING_PERIOD_TOKEN = "___DANGLING_PERIOD_TOKEN___";
```

Then in tokenize()

```
//a period following whitespace, not followed by a digit is a "dangling period"
code = code.replaceAll("(?<=\\s)\\.(?![0-9])", " "+DANGLING_PERIOD_TOKEN+" ");
```

And in the tokenization loop

```
case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
  // A word was found; the value is in sval
  String word = st.sval;
  if(word.equals(DANGLING_PERIOD_TOKEN))
    tokens.add(new SymbolToken('.'));
  else
    tokens.add(new WordToken(word));
  break;
```

This solution is specific to my needs of not caring what the original whitespace was (as it adds some around the inserted "token")